# Flexbox align-self:flex-start/end is adjusting horizontally not vertically

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

In my flex container, I have made it

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

For some reason, the child element is not adjusting to the top of the container element but is instead adjusting horizontally. Am I doing something incorrect with flex?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/siddrajpoot/pen/vjbRyy)

If you delete the child element css. It adjusts back to horizontally center.

Comment: Hello, can you explain how it should look? i don't really get the problem..

Comment: You want the title to be placed on the top of the container and the content to be on the center, right ?

Comment: That's because of the `flex-direction: column` which switches axes.

Comment: I agree with VXp, get rid of the flex-direction: column. Try it on your codepen and it works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to display the `title` element at the top center of the page and the content far below it, you can use

```
.title {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  padding: 2.4rem;
}
```

and for the content

```
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

This should do the trick. In any other case adjust the margins or just remove them and the `content` element will go under the title.

Comment: Perfect that worked! I guess I'm just a little confused because I thought the whole point of using `flex-direction: column; align-items: center` on the container and `align-self: flex-start` on the child would move the child to the top of the container